# Excel - How to select just copied sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have following lines of code as a part of my VBA macro.

```
Sheets("sheetName").copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
Set copySheet = Sheets(Sheets.count)
```

Above code should copy the sheet with name, sheetName, then set that copied sheet into copySheet. It somehow runs correctly from the second time I run the macro. At the first time, it selects the wrong sheet.

Because, the sheet that I wish to copy is hidden, I don't think I can use `Set copySheet = ActiveSheet`, either.

So, as a solution, I am looking for a method or variable which I can select the 'copied sheet'. Does VBA have such a command or variable?

Comment: This worked fine for me - can you post your full code?

Answer (score 0):

"Active" objects aren't always great to use but the following is an alternative:

```
Sub SetSt()

Dim copySheet As Excel.Worksheet

Sheets("sheetName").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set copySheet = Sheets(Excel.ActiveSheet.Name)

End Sub
```

For me, irrespective of whether sheets are hidden, like Brettdj I have no problems with your original code.